# graph api me/messages endpoint doesn't allow start and end DateTime in select list

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to list down all my meetings with a certain email id. I only want to select few things out of the huge response. Duration is one of the main insight and it won't allow to return the start and end datetime.

URL:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$select=startDateTime,subject,from,sender,toRecipients&$search="participants:xyz@contoso.com and kind:meetings"
```

Error I am getting is

```
"message": "Could not find a property named 'startDateTime' on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.Message'
Is this expected?
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for how to query all meetings ? but your query is for messages. Can you please clarify?

If you are looking for help with messages from specific person along with created data time you can update your query like this -
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$select=createdDateTime,Id,lastModifiedDateTime,from,subject&$filter=from/emailAddress/name eq 'XYZ A'